# Validating JQuery autocomplete using client_side_validations in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete, client-side-validation

I jave job which belongs_to client. I want to validate presence of client_id in jobs/new form. I am using jQueryUI autocomplete for picking client and I use client_side_validations for validations. After selecting client, I have javascript code to set value to client_id, but it is hidden_field which is not included in client side validations. Is there any way to validate its presence without modifying rails.validations.js?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying **:validate => true** upon the entire form will generally do the trick. However, you can validate specific fields by targeting them directly with:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :validate => { :presence => true } %>
```

Comment: this is how my search looks like:
<%= f.text_field :client_name, :placeholder=>"Type client name", data: {autocomplete_source: clients_autocomplete_path} %>

But I need to validate presence of client_id....

Answer (score 0):

I found trick for client side validation with rails auto complete
let auto complete field for company name

```
<% f.text_field :company_name %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :company_name, ...%>
```

this will work without any problem